# Hacer aparecer un DIV desde php

Tags: php, css

Como puedo hacer para que desde un `php` modificar un valor de `css`

Tengo un formulario de acceso de usuarios super sencillo, pero quiero que al comprobarse que ese usuario está registrado le aparezca un `div` que previamente estaba oculto en el cual tendrá diferentes enlaces y opciones.

A continuación muestro lo que se me ha ocurrido. Como yo solo sabía hacer esto con `JS` he intentado hacerlo así. ¿Como se haría?

```
if ($filas>0) {
    header("location: index.html");

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#sub-header').fadeOut();
    </script>

}else{
    header("location: index.html");
}
```

Como se hace para hacer modificaciones desde un `php`. Desde `JS`no tengo problema, pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo desde aquí.

¡Salud!

Comment: Podrias pasar un parametro en la url y asi verificar si vas o no a enseñar el div.

Comment: La clave de tu pregunta creo que está aquí: ***pero quiero que al comprobarse que ese usuario está registrado*** ... pregunto: ¿ **dónde** tendría que comprobarse que el usuario está registrado o no? Imagino que en el servidor, buscando en una base de datos o algo así. En ese caso, lo mejor es usar Ajax. Funciona básicamente así: 1. desde el cliente recoges los datos que introducirá el usuario y los mandas al servidor: 2. en el servidor verificas la existencia del usuario enviando por ejemplo más datos sobre él si fuera necesario y retornando la respuesta al cliente; 3. en el cliente recibes..

Comment: ... la respuesta que se obtuvo en el servidor y si la misma te dice que encontró al usuario desbloqueas/muestras el contenido reservado para él, actualizando el DOM (sin refrescar la página), en cambio, si te dice que no encontró al usuario, muestras un mensaje diciendo que no se encontró. Todo esto ocurrirá de forma transparente para el usuario y sin tener que refrescar la página.

Comment: Pues te voy a ser sincero @A.Cedano, tienes toda la razón pero no se como se hace. Estoy haciendo pruebas pero no me aclaro ¿si me dedico a intentar eso, debo preguntar aquí editando mi pregunta o genero un post nuevo?

Comment: Quizá convendría que replantees la pregunta, mostrando los intentos que estás haciendo y explicando el problema actual. En un principio la pregunta es muy básica como para poder dar una solución que sea óptima para ti, por eso , si te decides por Ajax (que sería lo mejor) debes mostrar al menos un punto de partida en ese sentido.

Comment: @A.Cedano la he formulado en otro post, porque aunque esta no sea la solución optima, me interesa el como se podría hacer. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175860/mostrar-nuevos-elementos-mediante-ajax-si-el-login-es-correcto

Comment: Con php exclusivamente lo mejor que se me ocurre es que utilices iframes en combinación con una variable de control al estilo bandera (muy primitivo). Es la solución estándar cuando excluyes el uso de javascript. Es en extremo necesario que no utilices javascript? Antes lo hubiese comprendido por los [fallos de seguridad graves que poseía javascript](http://blog.capacityacademy.com/2012/10/19/que-es-javascript-ventajas-y-desventajas/) y ciertos inconvenientes de rendimiento pero ahora no veo por qué excluirlo.

Comment: para nada excluyo JS, pero ese if-else viene de la comparación de una base de datos, por eso emplee PHP. Es ha sido mi problema, que como soy nocato autodidacta, con JS lo se hacer, pero al aparecer PHP me he perdido :S

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlocon js, desde php usas un `echo` y listo, algo asi:

```
if ($filas>0) {
header("location: index.html");

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#sub-header").fadeOut();
</script>';

}else{
header("location: index.html");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero sigue sin funcionar, me sigue saltando un error como de código no válido :( ¿podría ser por estar empleando jquery?

Comment: Es importante que se asegure de que jquery se importe antes que el script que escribimos con el `echo`, por tanto, el script php que incorpore esta parte tendría que ir en la parte final del archivo. @NEA