# mostrar nuevos elementos mediante ajax si el login es correcto

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, formularios

tengo la siguiente idea

1) Usuario rellena un formulario sencillo (nick y pass).

2) Se comprueba en la base de datos y si es afirmativo tiene acceso a nuevas pestañas, elementos de la página previamente ocultas.

**Importante** quiero emplear tecnología `AJAX`

Por lo tanto yo he hecho lo siguiente,

1.1) Formulario en `html` el cual el atributo `action` me dirige a trabajar con mi fichero `jquery` que trabajará con `AJAX`.

1.2) Con fichero `jquery` ejecuto un fichero `php` el cual valida en la base de datos si el usuario existe.

En caso afirmativo quiero que por ejemplo aparezca un `div` que hasta ahora estaba oculto.
En caso negativo, volvemos al punto anterior para que escriba bien su usuario o contraseña.

**Por lo tanto:** ¿Como hago para que mi `php` mande si el login es correcto o no a mi `jquery` y por lo tanto este enseñe o no el `div`?

A continuación dejo mi código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "validar.php",
    success: function(result) {
      $('#sub-header').css('display', 'flex');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
#sub-header {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sub-header">  <!-- Este está oculto hasta haberse logueado -->
  <a href="FormularioPropuesta.html"> Form. propuesta </a>
</div>

<form action="ajaxProyectos.js" method="post">
  <h2 class="texto">Log In</h2>
  <input type="text" name="usuario" class="texto" required placeholder="Nombre">
  <input type="password" name="clave" required placeholder="Contraseña">
  <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
</form>
```

```
<?php

// Obtengo los datos introducidos en el formulario de log in

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$clave = $_POST['clave'];

// Conectar a la base de datos
$bd_host = "localhost"; 
$bd_usuario = "root"; 
$bd_password = ""; 
$bd_base = "carrot";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($bd_host, $bd_usuario, $bd_password); 
mysqli_select_db($conexion,$bd_base); 
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios_pass WHERE usuarios='$usuario' and password='$clave'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if ($filas>0) {
    header("location: index.html");

}else{
    header("location: index.html");
}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysql_close($conexion);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es que ocultar un div no impide que un usuario pueda acceder a el, por que has de entender que un div oculto es solo eso un div oculto que esta ya ahi, pero no protegido.

Aparte de esto, concatenar valores externos directamente en la consulta es peligroso ya que abre la puerta a la inyección de SQL.

Dicho esto si lo que buscas es retornar una respuesta correcta o no a la petición ajax sin más, lo más adecuado es retornar las cabeceras existentes para tal fin, no tiene ningún sentido enviar una redirección, como estas haciendo.

Estas cabeceras podrían ser:

> **200 OK**
>   Respuesta estándar para peticiones correctas.

y

> **401 Unauthorized**
>   Similar al 403 Forbidden, pero específicamente para su uso cuando la autentificación es posible pero ha fallado o aún no ha sido provista

---

¿Cómo enviar estas cabeceras?

Fácil, en lugar de utilizar `header("location: index.html");` utilizamos el formato `header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");`

Ejemplo:

```
if ($filas>0) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
}else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el detalle del comentario. ¿Entiendo entonces que no se haría así? Es que esta es la manera como se me ha ocurrido a mí jaja, pero como se puede comprobar soy novato y autodidacta

Comment: El caso es que no queda claro que es realmente lo que estas haciendo, para proporcionarte una respuesta más completa requeriría de más información y el contexto. A priori solo te diría que no, que como práctica puede valer, pero tal y como está para un sistema en producción seria una pésima idea, ya que en ningún momento quedarían los datos protegidos, además de tener una brecha en tu base de datos.